# Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I have 2 springboot service. 1 springboot service is connected to localhost:27107 Mongodb. Another springboot service is connected to 172.**.***.***:27018 (Hosted somewhere). Both codes are the same except for the MongoClient connection values.

This is the code below.

```
    MongoClient mongoClient;
    MongoDatabase database;

    public FeedStorage() {
        mongoClient = MongoClients.create(FeedConfig.MONGODB_HOST);
        database = mongoClient.getDatabase(FeedConfig.DATABASE_NAME);
    }
```

For the 2nd springboot service, I am getting error

```
Caused by: com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(InternalStreamConnection.java:543)
        at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:428)
```

But the 1st one is okay. I am not sure why this is happening. Is localhost and hosted connection different?

Answer (score 1):

When the connection between the mongodb server and the client fails (such as a sudden interruption of the network link), the client does not actively reclaim these connections by default, and the above error occurs when the connection is read and written again.

you  can  set  the `maxConnectionIdleTime` in `MongoClientOption` when create  `mongoClient`

```
@Configuration
public class MongoDbSettings {

    @Bean
    public MongoClientOptions mongoOptions() {
        return MongoClientOptions
            .builder()
            .maxConnectionIdleTime(60000)
            .build();
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a reason the maxConnectionIdleTime value is 60000? should we set it to a much higher value like infinity etc?

Comment: maxConnectionIdleTime  is  the maximum idle time, in milliseconds, which must be >= 0. A zero value indicates no limit to the life time.    This is just an example  I used  ,you can  set  it  to  0