# I cannot connect to mongo db atlas using spring boot

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-atlas

I have a spring microservice application linked with mongodb atlas database, yesterday my project works fine but today I'm getting this error

```java
2022-11-24 00:29:33.267  INFO 5588 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server ac-bl3jxj4-shard-00-02.wt2swod.mongodb.net:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Exception receiving message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateReadException(InternalStreamConnection.java:707) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:579) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:415) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:342) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:96) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:44) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:131) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.startHandshake(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:73) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:182) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:152) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.setSoTimeout(Socket.java:1154) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.setSoTimeout(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:637) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.setSoTimeout(SSLSocketImpl.java:75) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:133) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:718) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessageWithAdditionalTimeout(InternalStreamConnection.java:576) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.4.2.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

here is my application.properties file

```java
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://denver:*****@product-service.wt2swod.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
spring.data.mongodb.database=product-service

eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka

spring.application.name=product-service
server.port=0
```

I tried to add those properties but never worked

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {
  MongoAutoConfiguration.class, 
  MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class
})
```

Comment: This may help your https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57367739/caused-by-com-mongodb-mongosocketreadexception-exception-receiving-message

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to - -> set socketKeepAlive to true (which is by default true in the latest versions of the native driver) -> set maxConnectionIdleTime < net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time in this way your JVM would reap the connection and not the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was connecting to the Atlas cluster through my local machine. I had to whitelist my IP address through the Atlas dashboard again.

[Whitelist your current IP address in your mongo DB cluster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7S4W6.png)

Check "Whitelist your current IP address in your mongo DB cluster" in this article for more information. https://baraksaidoff.medium.com/fixing-mongoserverselectionerror-while-connecting-mongodb-with-node-js-213aaf0bf596